# Call to AJAX jQuery function not doing anything, and unexpected calling of function on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to convert the pieces of php code on my website that access an sql database to ajax, so I don't have to refresh the page, and am having some problems getting things to work.

I've written an ajax jquery function (`getLatestData()`) that sets the values of html elements to the ones returned from the request to the php page. This function is stand alone (i.e. isn't triggered by an action on an element, it is just a function on its own) and works completely fine, retrieving the data from the database and correctly putting it in the fields.

However, I am unable to call the function manually. This is supposed to happen every minute (using javascript's `setInterval()` and a check to see if the current second is 2), so new data is loaded in every minute (the second `setInterval()` section in my code). This also works fine, as I have tried alerting from it. But, if I swap that statement with a call to my ajax function, nothing happens. Why is this? How do you call an ajax jquery function?

Also, my ajax function keeps getting called whenever the page loads (this is the only reason I know the function works), despite there being absolutely no other calls to it other than the one I am trying to get working (and it still happens even when this call is removed). Is this a function of ajax itself or is there something wrong with my code? How can I stop this happening?

Code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Remote Latest Data Warwick</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/jpeg" href="favicon.jpg">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/defaultstyles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/globalstyles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/globalscripts.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(function getLatestData() {
        alert("success1");

        $.ajax({
          type: "get",
          url: "retrieve/getlatestreport.php",
          dataType: "json",

          success: function(response) {
            alert(response[1]);

            document.getElementById("fAmbientTemperature_DryThermometer").innerHTML = response[0];
            document.getElementById("fAmbientTemperature_ExposedThermometer").innerHTML = response[1];
            document.getElementById("fSoilTemperature_10CentimetresDown").innerHTML = response[2];
          }
        });

      });
    });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function onLoad() {
      updateCurrentSystemTime();

      // Update number of seconds to data refresh
      setInterval(function() {
        seconds = 60 - new Date().getSeconds() + 3;

        if (seconds > 59) {
          seconds = seconds - 60;
        }

        document.getElementById(
          "timeToUpdate").innerHTML = seconds;
      }, 100);

      // Refresh page on third second of minute
      setInterval(function() {
        current = new Date();

        if (current.getSeconds() == "2") {
          //location.reload();
          //alert("t3");
          getLatestData();
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first snippet of code runs on page load, and causes an AJAX request. You have `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`, which means: wait until the HTML has loaded, then call the function. Then you have `$(function getLatestData() { ... });`, which means: wait until the HTML has loaded, then call `getLatestData`. So overall, this means wait until it's loaded, then check to make sure it's loaded, then call `getLatestData`. This is why it does the AJAX request on page load.

(Needless to say, you don't have to do the waiting for HTML part twice. In fact, I don't think it's necessary at all for an inline script - it's only for when the script is in its own file, like `globalscripts.js`, when there's a danger that it could load and try to run the script before the page has loaded.)

As for why the AJAX call doesn't happen when you try to trigger it, you haven't said where/whether you're setting the handler. For instance, you could have `<button id="reload-button">Reload</button>` and `$('#reload-button').click(onLoad);`.

If you're already doing something like this, or if you add these two lines, you should see an error message in the console saying that it can't call `getLatestData` because it's undefined. If you don't know what I mean by the "scope" of a variable, look it up. `getLatestData` is declared and defined in the scope of the anonymous function in the `$(document).ready` call. Therefore, it can only be used inside that function. I've already pointed out that you can get rid of the `document.ready` part. If you do that, then `getLatestData` will be declared and defined in the global scope, and the AJAX call should work.

In summary, you should replace your first inline script with `function getLatestData() { ... }`.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but is there no way I can define an ajax function stand alone, without a handler or trigger. This is what I was trying to do with my `getLatestData()` definition, so I could call it manually from some point in the code, instead of having it called upon interaction with the page elements. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: I've added another line to my answer. Hope that clears things up.